# Search/Filter/Sort on constantly changing 1 million documents

Tags: elasticsearch, solr, in-memory-database

My use-case is I have max 1 Million documents and documents getting updated constantly (once every 5 mins). Each document has almost 40 columns and I have sort/filter/search requirements on almost every column.

Since the documents are changing constantly, the doc value 5 minutes earlier is not valid anymore. I am thinking that an ideal DB component will need to be running in memory. For the other use-cases in the application (where documents do not change constantly), I am using ElasticSearch cluster. So to be consistent with the search elsewhere in the application, I want to explore if I can run a separate ES node/cluster purely in memory for my use-case above. I could not find any examples or precursors for running ElasticSearch in production in a pure in-memory configuration.

If not ES, can I run Apache Solr in memory? I can try out any technology which allows me to run in a pure in-memory mode, and provide functionality similar to ES (free text search at a per-column level).

What would you recommend for this use-case?

Comment: 1M doc updates per 5 mins, sounds like 3.3k doc updates per sec? tell about the read and write throughput capacity you want to achieve.

Comment: Reads are not from application UI. So it won't be a lot. Probably 20% of writes. As you said, write throughput is 3300 doc updates/sec. New documents will also come in and equal number of documents will be deleted. But that will be at a slightly lesser rate. Probably 300 inserts/deletes per sec.

Comment: How many of these values are changing? Is it 1m new, distinct documents each five minutes? Both Solr and Elasticsearch supports `memory` as a storage type to store the Lucene index files directly in memory, the rest is usually up to the caches. Unless the full-text search requirements are important, something like Redis could also be a decent choice (and would allow for close-to-real-time updates.

Comment: No. It is not new distinct documents every 5 mins. 90% are updates to existing documents and 10% will be deletes & inserts (old documents removed and new documents inserted). Unfortunately full text search is also an use-case.